# Writing out triple integrals - do x, y, and z have to be in order?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I’m currently working on some problems in Multivariable Calculus and am wondering if there is any stipulation that when writing out triple integrals, they must be x - then y - then z or else z - then y - then x. I have never seen it any other way and I am wondering if perhaps this is a property of the Cartesian coordinate system, just like when drawing our x,y,z axes they must be in order (counterclockwise like angles)?

Comment: If the integral exists, it should be the same regardless of how you measure it. But some orientations will be easier than others.

Comment: The order doesn't matter, but if you want to impose an order, one technique is to write:  $$\int dx \int dy \int dz f(x,y,z)$$

Comment: Cf. [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

Comment: "*just like when drawing our x,y,z axes they* **must** *be in order (counterclockwise)*"  No, they don't.  Do not confuse something being *conventional* with something being *required*.  It is conventional but not required that we draw our axes like that.  It is conventional but not required to write integrals with the variables appearing in alphabetical order when possible and changing the order does not affect the difficulty of the problem.  There is nothing intrinsically wrong with an integral like $\int\limits_{-1}^1\int\limits_{-1}^1\int\limits_{-1}^1f(x,y,z)~dz~dx~dy$

Comment: Wow! Thank you, everyone. And J.W., that article is really, really helpful and interesting. I so much appreciated that link, thank you so very much.

Comment: And JMoravitz, that’s really wild but also interesting! Do you have an example of a problem drawn with the axes in a non-conventional way? I learned that one must always draw the axes in the conventional way, or it is incorrect. But in space, they are all perpendicular, is that the idea? Thanks again.

Comment: @Yelena "Ordering the axes" is essentially just choosing an angle from which to look at that space. Given how useful looking at things from different perspectives is, limiting yourself to just one like that is an outright bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a key result called the *Fubini-Tonelli Theorem* (and a variety of related results) that roughly says that for any reasonable function, it does not matter what order you do the integrals in. Writing it down (actually two nested copies of it) in the $\mathbb{R}^3$ case, it becomes: For any measureable function $f$, we have

$$\int |f| dxdydz = \int |f| dxdzdy = \int |f| dydxdz = \int |f| dydzdx = \int |f| dzdxdy = \int |f| dzdydx,$$ and if $\int |f| dxdydz < \infty,$ then
$$\int f dxdydz = \int f dxdzdy = \int f dydxdz = \int f dydzdx = \int f dzdxdy = \int f dzdydx.$$

Note that the assumption that $\int |f|dxdydz < \infty$ is necessary for the latter part. In particular,
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}dydxdz = \frac{\pi}{4},$$ but $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}dxdydz = \frac{-\pi}{4}.$$

The problem is that $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|dxdydz = \infty,$$ so the above does not apply.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really interesting but I am a little bit confused about the idea of the magnitude of f - why would the absolute value change things? Is the absolute value always convergent? Also, if a function DOES diverge, is the possible order narrowed to just one possibility or to two by convention - what determines a “correct” answer if different answers are possible?

Comment: @Yelena For the first question: to prove this result, we actually prove it for *non-negative* functions, then write whatever function we're interested in as the difference of two non-negative functions $f_+$ and $f_-$, then prove our result by writing $\int f dxdy = \int f_+ dxdy - \int f_- dxdy = \int f_+ dydy - \int f_- dydx = \int f dydx$. If the integral of the absolute value is infinite, it's possible that those middle two terms are $\infty - \infty$, which is undefined.

Comment: @Yelena For the second question: No, it's not the case that $\int |f|$ always converges. Take, for example, any non-negative function for which $\int f|$ does not converge. 
For the third question: the question does. It's not that there's multiple answers: it's that there's multiple questions, and their answers are not the same in this particular case.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for these clear explanations. I’ll have to look into this some more.